# To open the already opened tab using window.open() function without reloading the already opened tab

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, window.open

I was writing OnClick javascript code to open the new web page.

**Expectation:**
I want my to open the new page if that page is not already openend or open the already existing page **without reload** if that page is already opened.

My code:
window.open(url,'dialers').focus();

This code always reloads the child page if already opened. Please help to achieve my ask.

Comment: When you open the page, save a reference to the page returned by `window.open()`, then just keep calling `.focus()` on that reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the window object into a variable and call the `focus()` method multiple times like this:

```js
let newWindow = window.open(url,'dialers')
newWindow.focus()
doThing()
newWindow.focus()
doAnotherThing()
newWindow.focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduced the `history.pushState(page, caption, replace_url)` that should not reload your page. OR if you want to modify while page load you can do this.

```
var currentURL = www.getitsol.com;
window.location.replace(currentURL + "?data=" + data.result, "_self");
```